# Django Folders Permissions Setup?

Tags: linux, django, apache, ubuntu, filesystems

Since I am having a Django

```
 PermissionError at /
```

I need to change permissions on my folders.  My question is what is the right level of permission for those folders which still secures my server? I use Apache on Ubuntu.

Comment: what code r your running at '/'? need to see that. are you trying to create any file on that url?? please post the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you need to set **r-x** for group owner, which must be www-data, and can use **rwx** for owner, which must be your user; only directories which www-data need to write (as repository for media files uploaded by clients) must be **rwx** for group owner.

For a more specific answer you need to provide some context about your issue:  where are your files placed?, when do you get that error?